# PHP Mail Error "The Page at X Says: E-Mail can not be sent!"

Tags: php, email, forms, sendmail

I have a simple contact page set up with a form and I am sending those details via email using the php mail() function.

When I submit the page everything works fine and the email sends with all the data no problems.

However once it has done this I get a popup in the browser that says:

"The page at (address) says:
E-mail can not be sent!"

even though this message is not true and the email sends fine I need to stop this from appearing as it halts my page's execution and no more code is ran after this. I can't seem to find anything about this error on google.

here is my mail code anyway just in case it is me causing it.

```
$headers  = "From: ".$Email."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$msg = '
 <html>
 <body>
 <strong>Enquiry from www.mysite.com website</strong><br /><br />
 <strong>Name:</strong> '.$FullName.' <br />
 <strong>Email:</strong> '.$Email.' <br />
 <strong>Phone:</strong> '.$Phone.' <br />
 <strong>Message:</strong> '.$Message.' <br />
 <strong>Group Size:</strong> '.$GroupSize.' <br />
 <strong>Date From:</strong> '.$DayFrom.' '.$MonthFrom.' '.$YearFrom.' <br />
 <strong>Date To:</strong> '.$DayTo.' '.$MonthTo.' '.$YearTo.' <br />
 <strong>Meals Required:</strong> '.$MealsRequired.' <br />
 <strong>Lift Pass Required:</strong> '.$LiftpassRequired.' <br />
     <strong>Equipment Required:</strong> '.$SkiRequired.' <br />
 </body>
 </html>
 ';
```

mail($sendTo, $subject, $msg, $headers);

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if it's an error from another part of the page, probably JavaScript. I'd look through your JS to see if there is anything pertaining to your error there. The error LOOKS like part of the PHP, but PHP is server side, not client side, so cannot trigger errors.

If you have any JS that runs near or when the mail is sent, have a look through that for any errors it may be throwing up.

James

Comment: Ahh yes you are correct, it was a function in the validation jQuery plugin that was no longer needed as it was being handled by PHP.

Comment: Look up HEREDOCs (http://php.net/heredoc). They'll help turn that huge ugly message string building into a trivial exercise.